# How to move logs from DB to some other archive format in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, logging

I have tables that consist of logs which after a certain amount of time the logs should be moved to some other archive format and removed from my database.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: [Data Pump Export](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624)

Comment: Any other approach? Or is this the only way to do it?

Comment: What are the requirements for the "other archive format"?  Does it need to be a text file that some other tool can process?  Is it going to be loaded into a different Oracle database where the archived data is stored?  Do you need to be able to re-load the data in the future if the business needs to run queries on old data?